# If statement targeting string

Tags: c#, pixelsense

I'm new to C# and I am trying to develop an application for a Microsoft PixelSense using Surface 2.0 SDK and C#.

I'm loading my items into my dropdown menu using a string as followed:

```
_Menu1.ItemsSource = new string[] {
    "All",
    "Housing",
    "Transportation",
    "Food",
    "Personal Insurance",
    "Health",
    "Entertainment",
    "Personal care",
    "Cash",
    "Misc",
};
```

Now I want to call an if statement if for example "Housing" is selected. The if statement should then enable a button.

I tried the following:

```
if (_Menu1.ItemSource == 1){
    _Menu3.IsEnabled = true;   
};
```

This is obviously not working but it illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Does `_Menu1` have have a `.SelectedIndex`, `.SelectedValue`, or equivalent?

Comment: `I'm new to C# and I am trying to develop an application for a Microsoft Pixelsense` - You seem to not have experience in OOP in general. That's evident by the way you are expecting to compare (via the `==` operator) an integer value with an `object` property, which has been assigned an `Array<string>`. I would suggest that you research and learn the basics of C# and OOP before trying to get into complex frameworks or applications.

Comment: Just to ensure we all know what classes you are working with, is it the `ItemsControl`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611045.aspx

Comment: What's the type of `_Menu1`?

Comment: @DanPichelman How do I check this? I guess not actually..

Comment: @Torylon, what type is it?!

Comment: @Arran I fixed the problem but I think the type is ModeSelector. Im not sure tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't that be:

```
_Menu1.SelectedIndex == 1
```

Comment: @Torylon, well where are you checking that value?

Comment: Inside my Public SurfaceWindow1() I got:  if (_Menu1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {     
                _Menu3.IsEnabled = true;
                _Menu3.Opacity = 1; 
            };

Comment: @Torylon: okay, so that's the constructor. In the constructor, the `SelectedIndex` would be either `-1` if you checked **before** loading the values or `0` if you checked after. You have to give the user a chance to change the value. You're going to need to check that value somewhere else.

Comment: Ah I got it. How would I check this value as soon as their is an item selected? So like a public void that gets called as soon as the menu dropdown is released.

Comment: @Torylon, consume the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like index values hardcoded. So:

```
        var dataString = new string[]
                                    {
                                        "All",
                                        "Housing",
                                        "Transportation",
                                        "Food",
                                        "Personal Insurance",
                                        "Health",
                                        "Entertainment",
                                        "Personal care",
                                        "Cash",
                                        "Misc",
                                    };

        _Menu1.ItemsSource = dataString;

        var index = dataString.ToList().IndexOf("Housing");

        _Menu1.SelectedIndex == index;
```